# Linking with GCC and -lm doesn't define ceil() on Ubuntu

Tags: c, math.h

I am currently using GCC to compile and I need to use `<math.h>`.
The problem is that it won't recognize the library.

I have also tried `-lm` and nothing.

The function I tried to use was `ceil()` and I get the following error:

```
: undefined reference to `ceil'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using the latest Ubuntu and *math.h* is there.
I tried to use [-lm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l) on a different computer, and it worked perfectly.

How can I solve this problem?

I did include `<math.h>`.  Also, the command I used was:

```
gcc -lm -o fb file.c
```

Comment: Can you give the full command line you're using?

Comment: And did you remember `#include <math.h>` before you use `ceil`?

Comment: I did include math.h
Also, the command I used was:
gcc -lm -o fb file.c

Comment: Did you specify `-lm` *after* the source file name?

Comment: There's your trouble - specify libraries after the source file name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! Didn't think that the order of the flags mattered.

Comment: @rum `-l` are not flags - they are library names, and thus are relevant, because everything unneeded of a library gets thrown out immediately. If it turns out later that it wasn't unneeded, it is too late.

Comment: Actually, there's a strong case for saying `-lm` options are flags; they can also be written `-l m` (but very seldom are written thus).  Also, the behaviour you describe is correct for static libraries (`.a` on Unix), but doesn't really apply to shared libraries.

Comment: Order of arguments to `gcc` *matters a lot*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take this code and put it in a file `ceil.c`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%f\n", ceil(1.2));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with:

```
$ gcc -o ceil ceil.c
$ gcc -o ceil ceil.c -lm
```

One of those two should work.  If neither works, show the complete error message for each compilation.  Note that `-lm` appears after the name of the source file (or the object file if you compile the source to object before linking).

Notes:

1. A modern compiler might well optimize the code to pass 2.0 directly to `printf()` without calling `ceil()` at all at runtime, so there'd be no need for the maths library at all.
2. **Rule of Thumb:** list object files and source files on the command line before the libraries.  This answer shows that in use: the `-lm` comes after the source file `ceil.c`.  If you're building with `make` etc, then you typically use `ceil.o` on the command line (along with other object files); normally, you should list all the object files before any of the libraries.

There are occasionally exceptions to the rule of thumb, but they are rare and would be documented for the particular cases where the exception is expected/required.  In the absence of explicit documentation to the contrary, apply the rule of thumb.

Comment: @Johnathan Leffler is there a way to do this without tpying -lm every single time during compiling?

Comment: @Brandon: Migrate to Mac?  The functions from `<math.h>` are in the main system library, so you don't need to specify `-lm` (though there is a `libm.dylib` to give you a library to link against if you specify `-lm` on the command line).  Otherwise, make sure you're using a makefile and you have `LDLIBS` (or `LDLIBES`) set to `-lm` if you use it enough to warrant it — or write per-program rules that include/exclude the library as required by each program.  So, in other words, "No, there isn't a way to avoid specifying it".  You could ask the GLibC team why they've not gone to a single library.

Comment: Note that if you optimize the code, it is possible for the compiler to evaluate `ceil(1.2)` at compile time and avoid the need to call the function at runtime, in which case you might not need the `-lm` library at all.  But that would be an obscure edge-case for the simple program in my example — in general, the compiler would not be able to make that optimization and then you'd need to link with the maths library unless the functions are already in the main system library.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed putting the flag after the file.

Answer (score 12):

I just wanted to mention that Peter van der Linden's book [Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) has a good treatment on this subject in chapter 5 [Thinking of Linking](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=specify%20libraries%20last%20expert%20c%20programming&source=bl&ots=Ho53S92GfY&sig=OLJ2EcglEZCLgFadrZSBw7OGZv8&hl=sv&ei=aVDPTpNj6oniBMnFpXw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=specify%20libraries%20last%20expert%20c%20programming&f=false).

> Archives (static libraries) are acted upon differently than are shared objects (dynamic libraries). With dynamic libraries, all the library symbols go into the virtual address space of the output file, and all the symbols are available to all the other files in the link. In contrast, static linking only looks through the archive for the undefined symbols presently known to the loader at the time the archive is processed.

If you specify the math library (which is usually a static one) before your object files, then the linker won't add any symbols.

Answer (score 8):

Try compiling like that:

```
gcc -Wall -g file.c -lm -o file
```

I had the same problem and it was solved using this command. Also if you installed your Ubuntu the same day you had the problem it might be an update problem.

Comment: This question has long been answered.

Comment: Rule of thumb: libraries after source or object files — this command line follows that RoT.