# C - Undefined reference to 'ceil' in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

I have problem which was mentioned here multiple times, but i still cant find out how to relsove it.

I want use **ceil()** function in NetBeans-IDE, but still getting error **Undefined reference to 'ceil'**. I tried add `-lm` into gcc compiler by project properties but no success.

Can someone help me how to solve this specific problem?

Comment: Have you included `<math.h>`?

Comment: Sure, i include math library.

Comment: This post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266183/linking-with-gcc-and-lm-doesnt-define-ceil-on-ubuntu

Comment: I tried code from that post, but still getting the same error

Comment: Where is `-lm` in the link line?  Before or after the object file that references `ceil()`?  You've not shown the linking command line, but if `-lm` occurs too soon, it may as well not be there.